# Having difficulties with "sudo apt-get update" after moving into another country

Tags: apt

I have moved temporarily from Turkey into Germany for 1.5 months and the code

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Does not work as intended producing lots of errors. In order to avoid it I tried deleting the following file from the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`; furthermore I commented out a few lines in the sources.list file up to no avail. Everytime the culprit is something different. 
    sudo rm ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-precise.list
    sudo rm ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-precise.list.save

The output of the `sudo apt-get update` command can be found in the following link:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7905503/

Here is the output for apt-config dump:

paste.ubuntu.com/7898595

The file containing "Acquire"

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};

// List of packages to not update
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
//  "vim";
//  "libc6";
//  "libc6-dev";
//  "libc6-i686";
};

// This option allows you to control if on a unclean dpkg exit
// unattended-upgrades will automatically run 
//   dpkg --force-confold --configure -a
// The default is true, to ensure updates keep getting installed
//Unattended-Upgrade::AutoFixInterruptedDpkg "false";

// Split the upgrade into the smallest possible chunks so that
// they can be interrupted with SIGUSR1. This makes the upgrade
// a bit slower but it has the benefit that shutdown while a upgrade
// is running is possible (with a small delay)
//Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";

// Install all unattended-upgrades when the machine is shuting down
// instead of doing it in the background while the machine is running
// This will (obviously) make shutdown slower
//Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";

// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed.
//Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root@localhost";

// Set this value to "true" to get emails only on errors. Default
// is to always send a mail if Unattended-Upgrade::Mail is set
//Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";

// Do automatic removal of new unused dependencies after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";

// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if a 
// the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade 
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";


// Use apt bandwidth limit feature, this example limits the download
// speed to 70kb/sec
//Acquire::http::Dl-Limit "70";
```

Comment: Please post your complete sources.list file. Either add it to your question, or use paste.ubuntu.com and post the link here. The first message suggests a syntax error in the file. Did you by any chance edit it manually?

Comment: @roadmr I have added the sources.list file thanks for your interest.

Comment: sorry, I don't see it :( Did you by any chance configure an apt proxy in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ ? that may also be affecting things. I'd really need to see your sources.list to tell you more.

Comment: @roadmr I added my sources.list file.

Comment: Thanks! The syntax of the sources.list file looks OK, so the problem lies somewhere else. Did you configure an apt proxy? if so, you probably modified a file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/. Can you have a look at those files and check that they are correct? If you need help with this, I suggest you look at any of those files mentioning a proxy and post its contents here so we can try to figure this out.

Comment: @roadmr I haven't configured a proxy but I will post the contents of the files in that directory. Which files are of importance? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: use `grep` to see if any of the files mentions "Acquire" and post the ones that mention this. Those modify the way apt-get fetches files and could be causing this problem.

Comment: @roadmr Updated my post one file mentions Acquire and its name is 50unattended-upgrades.

Comment: Thanks! That's not it unfortunately :/ see the Acquire section is commented out. Can you run `apt-config dump >/tmp/apt-config`, and then add that `/tmp/apt-config` file to your question? Better yet, use paste.ubuntu.com and then just post the link here to keep the answer short. This will how us the effective apt-get configuration, that way we can see what's going on.

Comment: @roadmr The link for that output is as follows http://paste.ubuntu.com/7898595/

Comment: OK, that looks fine to me, no problems there. One more thing. Can you look at files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d and see if the syntax looks OK? I suspect one of those may contain the error. If you want help reviewing them, pastebin them as you did the previous one.

Comment: @roadmr There are lots of files in that directory and it will be a real pain to check them all do you really think that this situation has nothing to do with me moving from one country into another?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the move; there's no reason for that, unless the networks are significantly different (i.e. needing a proxy) or you changed something manually. An example error message `Unable to connect to download.mendeley.com:http`, we can focus on this one, use `grep` to see if any file in sources.list.d mentions `mendeley` and check that one to see if the syntax is correct.

Comment: @roadmr There seems to be no problem with the mentioned files and when I execute the command 'apt-get update' another repository interferes with updating this time.

Comment: This is very strange, if you haven't changed anything but the repository giving trouble is different every time, at least it means your configuration should be OK. Can you try a different connection? maybe if it's a portable computer, go to an internet cafe or some other place? this would help rule out firewall or proxy problem in your network.

Comment: @roadmr You are right maybe I should try wired connection. Apart from that the Software Center just crashes and it cannot be opened; I reinstalled it and the problem was solved for sometime but it recurred. Furthermore, I have lots of crashes with apport-gtk and the system behaves in a weird way. By the way I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not get updates directly from System Settings>Software & Updates?

You can select where the Download comes from in this screen...

Apologies in advance if I have misunderstood your request.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the issue I think it has something to do with sources.list file or the files in the other directory.

Comment: Oh well, it as worth a mention anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because of the archive source center. Better check for update&support in system setting or change date&time zone.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

change every tr.archive.ubuntu.com to de.archive.ubuntu.com in /etc/apt/sources.list.

tr (Turkey's Alpha-2 code)
de (Germany's two Alpha-2 code)

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu 22.04 had same issue since I moved from Portugal, so I went there:

[Activities/Software Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrqNq.png)

Then I choose Other and Select Best Server. Ubuntu will test the update servers from your location and select the best performing ones.

Enjoy.